# Запрос с соединеним таблиц

Tags: sql

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться). Есть 2 талицы Emp с атрибутами `id`(номер сотрудника), `fio`(имя сотрудника), `id_o` (номер отдела) и Dep с атрибутами `id_o` (номер отдела), name (название отдела). Нужно вывести название отдела, в которых работает, например, 2 сотрудника. Почему в данном запросе не разрешается использование агрегатной функции (count)?

Вот пример запроса:

```
SELECT S.name 
   FROM Dep S, Emp P
   WHERE S.SNO=P.BNO AND count(P.id) = 2;
```

Comment: @AgerAn, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Emp1.id_o, COUNT( Emp1.id_o ) , Dep1.name
FROM Emp1, Dep1
WHERE Dep1.id_o = Emp1.id_o
GROUP BY Emp1.id_o
HAVING COUNT( Emp1.id_o ) =2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id) as `id_o`, count(*) as `count`, `name`
from `table`
where `count` = 2
group by `id_o`
```

Если в слепую писать, то как-то так.

---

Нет, не так. Две таблицы, не увидел.

Answer (score 0):

Функции семейства JOIN

```
 LEFT JOIN
 RIGHT JOIN
 INNER JOIN
```

Comment: Может знаешь, почему сдесь ругается на emp_col?
select dep.name, count(emp.id) as emp_col from dep inner join emp on dep.id_0 = emp.id_0 group by id_0 having emp_col > 2 ;

Comment: Структура таблиц одинаковая?

Comment: ну да, одинаковая

Comment: А если так переписать запрос:


    select dep.name, count(emp.id) as emp_col 
    from dep inner join emp on dep.id_0 = emp.id_0 
    group by id_0 
    having count(emp.id) > 2